# jquery-min version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I noticed that there is always a "min" version (stands for mini?) for most JavaScript libraries (e.g., jQuery).

What is the difference? Less functionality but smaller size?

Is this something someone should consider using? (There are a lot of min versions out there.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The functionality is exactly the same - just open the minified and the "normal" versions in a text editor and you'll see the difference.

The min-Versions are just there to provide reduced filesize, to save you bandwith and traffic ;-)

Answer (score 10):

> ...in computer programming languages and especially JavaScript, is the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code, **without changing its functionality**.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: Your link is missing the end bracket.

Answer (score 7):

Its been "minified". All the functionaility is there, just in a minified version that is smaller for saving transfer bandwidth.

Things to become "minified":

- Remvoing whitespace
- Renaming some variables - such as function-scoped variables, not function names.

Here is an example

```
function myFunction(someReallyLongParamName)
{
    someReallyCrazyName = someReallyLongParamName;
}
```

could be come

```
function myFunction(a){b=a;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Minified versions just have whitespace removed, to make them faster to download. Otherwise, they are identical.

Answer (score 2):

no, exactly the same function, the text has been minimized to reduce the download, this means you cant really debug in it but you do get the same functionality

Comment: you mean i cant open the file and read it? of course i dont want to...if i would like to i just download the real instead of including it in every html header? or have i missed the point?

Comment: you can open it and read it, it is just not very readable :) usually the none min file is used for development, the min file for production.

Answer (score 2):

Smaller size because all of the white space is removed from the file. Just open both files in text editor and you will see.

Answer (score 2):

This is a version of jQuery that has a smaller file size (minified).  Same functions, just a smaller file that the browser has to download.

Answer (score 1):

same functions...smaller size. Think of it as poor mans compression. They simply remove all unneccessary whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at jquery.com you'll usually see the minified version is classified as the "*production*" version.  Other than that, as others have said, they're the same file, one larger (byte size) than the other.