# Pixi.js vs Pixi.min.js differences?

Tags: pixi.js

I'm new to web development and currently learning Pixi.js and I noticed there are [few versions](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/releases):

```
Pixi.js
Pixi.js.map
Pixi.min.js
Pixi.min.js.map
```

May I know is there any differences between these in terms of features?

Comment: In web developement it's common to have 2 versions of a library. The "min" version is minified/compressed. It has the same functions but it's hard to step into in the browser's debugger as the code is nearly unreadable. So, generally you use the "min" version and ship with the "min" version but occasionally use the non min version for debugging

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711060/difference-between-d3-js-vs-d3-min-js and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071631/jquery-min-version

Answer (score 2):

they're not at all different version, it's just a common convention in javascript programming: "min.js" files are the "minified" lib source, that's mean the same ".js" file where spaces, end of line and other unnecessary (for the browser) characters are cut off, and also variables names were changed with shorter ones, to obtain a lighter source file, less heavy to download and easier to execute for the browser. This file is obviously automatically generated from tools like gulp and grunt and is the source file you have to upload to the server and finally serve to the user. ".map" files instead are, whell, maps who link minified files to their full size counterpart, whit just min and map files, chrome debugger can reconstruct the original source and show it to you in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question: No they are exactly the same, when it comes to features.**

A `*.min.js` file is just the `original.js` file but "minified".

That means names were shortened (e.g function `getName` changed to `n`).

It's size (bytes) is also reduced.